# Odd behavior of texts from software

Tags: microsoft-excel

I realize that sometimes texts in workbooks that my colleague sent to me have odd behaviours. They probably get these texts from internal software.

For instance, B2 is a text I copy-pasted from their workbook. Its format is already `Text`. E2 is a text I entered, whose format is `Text` too. G2 checks if they are the same, and returns `FALSE`.

Does anyone know the cause here? How could I convert the texts from my colleague to something I could use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not the "text" inside the cell, but the **text formatting** applied to the cell. You can change the *text* format to anything, such as *General* or *Number*, and then the equality test should yield TRUE.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm talking about the "text formatting". I tried to change it to `General` or `Number`, the equality is always `FALSE`.

Comment: Check for a hidden character such as a blank at the end?

Comment: @harrymc no, there is no hidden character.

Comment: And if you were to input your cursor into cell B2 and/or E2 then press enter, same behavior? Numbers formatted as text usually display the green arrow warning, but I don't see that in your image. Perhaps you turned that off. Also, you can copy that to Notepad ++, then turn on "show all characters" to see if there's something else not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I paste a number from one cell into another cell and then set the cell formatting to "text"; then use a pre-formatted-as-text cell to manually type the number; and then use your comparison, I get the same result.

There may be conversion issues you need to be aware of (might not be currency safe etc., check the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)), but if you use `=value(E2)=value(B2)` it should work.

side note: I believe I see a display-font difference between the two cells in your screen shot. Not sure if this is excel or if your pasted content has XML formatting tags embedded in it. This might cause an equality operator to see them differently.

Answer (score 0):

`Yorik` addresses the two main reasons this might happen. I am amplifying each.

First, formatting. One guesses — and GUESS is all we can do since you do not post a spreadsheet with the failure "working" as a failure — that you mean the cell from the colleague is itself already formatted as text and therefore this baffles one. But, subtle difference, but it would matter, if you mean the cell in YOUR sheet is pre-formatted as text and the pasting cell is not necessarily so, then that would give one a thought on what's happening. Outside of that, people often state "A THING" as a discrete fact when actually, they do not know it literally.

For instance, you could copy and paste the cell, see the numerical value appears at the left of the cell and think "It's text. It is numerical characters formatted as text because if formatted as numbers, they'd appear at the right edge of the cell. And my cell was formatted as text, so... they must be text." This is COMMON, everywhere in life (something to remember if ever a juror), so I'm not insulting you in any way. A reasoned conclusion is taken as the literal fact since the reasoning is considered utterly correct.

If so, and the material is not in fact formatted as text, just looks as if it is, then the cause would have to be extra material in the data. A lot of internet material for example has characters in it that help render it in a pleasing and useful manner. None of these are really addressed by `CLEAN()` or the mostly worthless short lists of other characters presented on websites.

And they can be entirely invisible, even in the Formula Editor. A careful person moving carefully from character to character with an arrow key and carefully, unblinkingly, might carefully notice one of this subgroup by seeing the cursor blink when the arrow key is pressed but otherwise have utterly no movement while another press does move. That character has no width AT ALL and hence is invisible to anything visual except a careful test like this.

What to do with the general idea of this angle? Enter the Formula Editor and copy all the content. Like <kbd>Shift-Control-Home</kbd> and copy. Exit the Editor and pick a blank cell that is formatted "General" or some numeric format. Enter the Editor for it and paste the other cell's content. Does it immediately display as a number? If yes, see later in this answer. If no, then there is extra material that you are NOT seeing and the mystery is solved. Removing it is another story that you would want to research or ask another question about.

That's a test even someone very convinced the other way can't really argue about. But `Yorick`'s `VALUE()` test is a great one too. Even just using it on the pasted cell, not doing his comparison, will tell you:  if it is a number, then nothing extra is present. If it is an error, then like it or not, believe it or not, there is extra material present.

So... "later in this answer"... If you determine it really is just the five numeric characters and there really is a text format on the cell, it becomes much more interesting. Given that you copy and paste if from a place where it is text already (unless, of course, that's not so:  see above about that), the usual concern would flat not be the case. The usual concern is that changing the format of a cell does NOT AT ALL mean Excel immediately sees it as the new format. So one changes a number cell to a text cell and the number in it remains a number. And vice-versa. At that point, and this arises very often, surprisingly, one must force ("Coerce" in Excel-speak) Excel to take the change into account.

I find saving the spreadsheet and re-opening it almost always does the trick. There are lots of other ways, but that takes care of all such cells in one fell swoop. Almost always. Bear in mind though that many things in Excel are quite sensitive to exact details so the material you work with may see a lower success rate from that method, or any of the other common methods. Or higher. In any case, give that a try. It may be that the foundation you are basing the bafflement upon is not exactly what you thought it was. Or it may not.

Another oddness that could happen is one could be pasting an image, not a cell. That could lead to what the pic shows.

Another test would be, after pasting the cell, type some other number in it and see what happens after typing the same number in your comparison cell. Typing, not pasting. The cell could be formatted as `;;;25119` and "horse" might be typed in it.  Or it's formatted `;;;@\9` with "2511" typed in it, or some other variations. Obviously, this is a very unlikely thing, and would be bizarre, but could happen. Also, not likely if 100 cells have this issue. But... colleague's sometimes have sport with other colleague's. All good fun I'm sure. Happens though.

Another way it could occur is if there is a (or several) Conditional Format laid on the cell. It would copy over when pasting. Just a simple rule `=ISNUMBER(cell address)` would be TRUE for the number 25119 and a number format of "text" could be chosen. So it would display as text due to the conditional format. Would it compare TRUE to a cell formatted as text with normal formatting? NO, it would NOT. It would (and does, I tested it) give a FALSE result. So there's another way this could occur. The colleague might have some reason for doing so. Perhaps he wishes to keep numbers as numbers for downstream uses but for display does not want the jarring numbers at the right in a column of mostly text to the left. Other reasons could apply as well.

Something to look for.

But the headline idea here, that the colleague somehow found a weirdness in Excel, is just not the case. I've been using it 30 years and only have found one display weirdness in Excel and that is just display for a rare use of text in a cell. The "value" of the material in the cell isn't part of the weirdness at all. There is a simple explanation, whichever one it might be, for what you are seeing.

To get something more definite than that, post a copy of an .XLSX (not an .XLSM) file in some repository (people enjoy DropBox here, amongst others) with a meaningful URL, not a "TinyURL" or other "could be hiding ANYTHING, which would hammer me if I open it" URL. If we can see PRECISELY what is there, we can tell you PRECISELY what is happening. In this case, a picture is not worth a thousand words. It's actually worthless.